# react-virtualized List: How to remove empty space when the list is too short?

Tags: react-virtualized

I am using react-virtualized List to render a list of data. When the list is too short (is height is smaller than the "height" prop of List component) there are a lot of empty spaces at the bottom (because the height is fixed). Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to detect when this is the case, and just pass a shorter `height` value to `List`.

This is what [react-virtualized-selected](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized-select/) does for short drop-down lists, for example. [You can see the code for that here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select/blob/96ab78949033a2ca32b4e3eca56ba115b9c6df46/source/VirtualizedSelect/VirtualizedSelect.js#L117-L133), although it may be more complicated than what you need because of the fact that it supports variable-height rows.

If your rows are fixed height, then the calculation is much simpler:

```
const height = Math.min(maxHeight, rowCount * rowHeight);
```